# Using wsimport to create a SOAP client but unable to get it to work with SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, soap, websphere, cxf, jax-ws

It's been a while since I've had to do any Java development, so perhaps I'm a bit rusty.  However, I've been tasked with creating a SOAP client that will be called within a IBM HATS (web) application.  No problem!  I'm using Rational Application Developer 9.7.0.1 and I simply imported the WSDL and generated the client classes.
The issue, though, is that this service requires an SSL certificate.  I've tried a ton of different things, but nothing I've done has been able to get this to work.
In addition to RAD 9.7.0.1, I'm using WebSphere Application Server 9 and Java 1.8.0_251.
I wanted to stick with just vanilla JAX-WS instead of introducing CXF/Spring.  So the first thing I tried was just setting the truststore properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "******");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

This still gives me the error an error that the certificate could not be found.

So I bit the bullet and tried using CXF 3.3.7 to set up the HTTPS connection -

```
//Set Up SSL Connection
SSLContext sslContext = null;
try
{
    KeyStore trustStoreInst = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
             
    trustStoreInst.load(CMPIDCASCustom.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(trustStore), 
                                                              trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
    tmf.init(trustStoreInst);
            
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
                
//Call the Service
SoaProxy service = new SoaProxy();
SoaProxySoap servicePort = service.getSoaProxySoap();
        
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider)servicePort;
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, 
                                 "https://myurl.com/soaproxy.asmx");
        
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(servicePort);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        
TLSClientParameters parameters = new TLSClientParameters();
parameters.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
http.setTlsClientParameters(parameters);
        
UserResponse userResponse =  servicePort.retrieveUser(param1, param2);
```

However, doing this gives me the following error:
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy

This seems to be a well-known error, however, trying to:

1. Upgrade org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection
2. Adding this code:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setAddress("https://blwq-auth.betasys.com/tsaproxyservice/soaproxy.asmx?wsdl");
factory.setServiceClass(SoaProxySoap.class);
SoaProxySoap servicePort = (SoaProxySoap) factory.create();
```

3. Or setting DisableIBMJAXWSEngine to true in my Manifest.mf and in the admin console does not seem to work.

Does anyone know the quickest, easiest way to get a SOAP client to work with an SSL certificate whether it be just using JAX-WS itself or with CXF?  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the client application is running inside WebSphere, the certificate from the web service needs to be added to WebSphere's trust store.  I found the process to do that here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_6.0.0.4/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0.0.4/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_config_was_ssl_dbservr.htm  (different product, but the process is the same.)

Comment: Currently, this is running on my local machine with a local instance of WAS.  I was under the impression that by specifying the javax.net.ssl.trustStore location, that the application would be able to find this.  We are doing something similar with the truststore that is used by the IBM HATS product for making connections to the mainframe.

Comment: Manipulating the truststore at the jvm level could work, but the documentation suggests a different approach.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tsec_sslretrievesignersport.html

Comment: Thanks Bruce T!  That link above was close to what I was able to get from an HCL resources... https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tsec_sslretrievesignersport.html.  And that seemed to do the trick after removing all the CXF stuff.  Still not sure how to get CXF to run in our version of WAS, but it's a moot point for now.